# Page Controller pattern vs Front Controller

Tags: java, laravel, mvc, design-pattern

O que é o Page Controller? O que é o Front Controller?
Pelo que eu li, page controller significa um controlador que esta embutido na pagina html/jsf facelet.

No entanto no Front Controller o controlador e a view estao separados.
(Eu sei como o MVC do laravel funciona, se conseguisem dar uma exemplo com laravel, possivelmente iria perceber melhor os padrões)

Eu li a definição de Martin Fowler, contudo como o nivel de abstracção e muito grande tenho bastantes dificuldade em perceber...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MVC` é um padrão geral. A idéia é separar três aspectos `(Modelo, Visão e Controle)` de um aplicativo um do outro. Agora, essa idéia pode ser realizada de maneiras diferentes de acordo com os detalhes de uma situação / aplicação. Uma maneira é ter muitos controladores, cada um respondendo a uma ação ou a um conjunto de ações. Outra maneira é ter um controlador principal que recebe todas as ações e, em seguida, as despacha para diferentes `controladores`, esta é chamada `Front Controller`. Assim, o padrão `Front Controller` **é um padrão MVC** . Por exemplo, o `Spring Framework`, `laravel` usa o padrão do `Front Controller` para realizar o `MVC`.